# What is the difference between jconn4.jar and jconn42.jar?

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase, jconnect

Basically in the installation SDK of Sybase 16 we have jconn4.jar and jconn42.jar. What is the difference between jconn4.jar and jconn42.jar?

Comment: Are their manifests different?  Do those manifests have Implementation-Version entries?

Comment: I think the only differences in MANIFESTS are in package naming and JDK compiled with: jconn4.jar -> 1.6, jconn42.jar -> 1.8

Comment: At a guess, one is for JDBC 4.0 (Java 6) and the other is for JDBC 4.2 (Java 8)

Answer (score 1):

jconn42 is newer and supports TLS.
jconn4 does not support TLS. There may be other small differences as well, but that is the big one I’m aware of.

Oh, the package names are also different: replace *.jdbc4.* with *.jdbc42.*